# Unable to redirect IO output in FreeBsd

Tags: bash, freebsd, shell

I have this:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/sh

$ uname -a
FreeBSD  11.0-RELEASE-p8
```

And this works:

```
sudo bash my_script.sh some_arg
```

But this not:

```
sudo bash my_script.sh some_arg >& /dev/null
```

Error:

```
-sh: Syntax error: Bad fd number
```

In Linux with default bash as a shell this works fine.

How to fix it?

In the script I have this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

# other stuff
```

Comment: You appear to have a spurious `&` character following the `>`.

Comment: @RichardSmith, I don't understand

Comment: `sudo bash myscript.sh some args > /dev/null`

Comment: @Kondybas, in Linux with the default shell  being bash all works fine with the `&`. Why? What does it depend on, OS or shell?

Comment: The only shell that I can find that uses `>&` is `csh`. Both `sh` and `bash` (on both FreeBSD and Linux) do not allow `>&` to redirect to a file.

Comment: @RichardSmith bash, Linux - does

Comment: I think `>&` is a Bashism only in `bash` >= 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bash` does support this, but you explicitly state that your current shell is not `bash`, but rather `sh`, which is a different shell.

Comment: what does >& mean?

Comment: It is a redirect of both stdout and stderr to the same endpoint.  It's shorthand for `1> /path/to/endpoint 2>&1`.

Answer (score 3):

`bash` does support `>&`, however `/bin/sh` does not (at least not for redirection to a file).

Your command line is interpreted by `/bin/sh` **before** being passed to `sudo` and `bash`.

I cannot test this on `bash` (but it works with other shells) - you could try using the `-c` option with a quoted string:

```
sudo bash -c "my_script.sh some_arg >& /dev/null"
```

Comment: what does `>&` mean?

Comment: It was in your question!! But if you are asking what it does, see the [manual page for bash(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bash) - section *Redirecting Standard Output and Standard Error*

Comment: yes, but what concreatly >& does?

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax would be:

```
sudo my_script.sh some_arg > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: why in reverse?

Comment: why not something like `sudo my_script.sh some_arg 2>&1 > /dev/null ` or `sudo my_script.sh some_arg >  2>&1 > /dev/null`?

Comment: The "sudo my_script.sh some_arg 2>&1 > /dev/null" won't work.  I'm not sure why; it has something to do with the order the file descriptors (stderr, stdout) are set up.